# Форматирование строк в php

Tags: php, строки

В текстовом файле некрасивые строки, например:

> 0000000438,add,file,10/24/2015,06:57:06,"Bank","6.20.31.32.00","2031/Main",

Я приводила их к следующему виду:

> 10.24.2015 06:57:06 Bank 6.20.31.32.00 2031.Main

Делала я это следующим образом:

```
$a_temp = file("temp66.txt");
                $num = count($a_temp); //количество строк в файле temp66.txt
                for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
                    $read = $a_temp[$i]; 
                    $string = substr($read, 20, -2);
                    //припудрим строки
                    $trans = array("/" => ".", "," => " ", "\"" => "");
                    $print = strtr($string, $trans);
```

Но на днях я обнаружила, что строки не форматируются. 
Как отформатировать строки другим способом?

Comment: Что значит "не форматируются"?

Comment: Владимир, видимо этот кусочек кода не работает.

Comment: приведенный кусок кода и пример работают - https://eval.in/521630

Comment: Работал. Отвалился на этой неделе. Мне больше интересно, с чего бы это вдруг... Может у меня и некрасивый вариант реализации в силу того, что я новичок, но он должеееееееен рабооооотать!!!! Оставлю пока вариант Jean-Claude через explode, пока не разберусь с тайной мадридского двора @splash58

Comment: а что этот вариант работает, а ваш нет? на одних и тех же входных данных?

Comment: так если что-то не форматируется, то надо это "что-то" и показывать, чтобы было ясно что именно не работает. А вообще ваш "некрасивый файл" очень даже похож на красивый csv, а значит и [читать строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) можно намного проще. Только если это правда csv, то зачем такие сложности с форматированием? Его же надо по назначению использовать, а не мучить )

Comment: Да. С explode заработало опять. Мой, видимо, устал работать. @splash58

Comment: Да мне всё равно как он выглядит. Я им и пользуюсь по назначению. Некоторые люди хотят, чтобы на страницу сайта выводился без кучи лишних символов. Да это и неважно уже.  @BOPOH

Comment: В качестве версии... А не стали ли в исходном файле появляться символы кириллицы?

Comment: Нет. Кириллицы нет. @newman

Comment: Когда я уже встречу в коммен тах такую фразу? =)) //припудрим строки

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer наверное, кроме меня людей с такими комментариями не найдется. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как [вариант](http://ideone.com/5sgBBv) с использованием explode():

```
$string = '0000000438,add,file,10/24/2015,06:57:06,"Bank","6.20.31.32.00","2031/Main",';
$trans = array("/" => ".", "\"" => "");
$string = strtr($string, $trans);

$arr = explode(',', $string);
unset($arr[0]);
unset($arr[1]);
unset($arr[2]);
unset($arr[8]);
$arr = implode(' ', $arr);
echo $arr;
```

Полностью ваш код соответственно будет таков:

```
$a_temp = file("temp66.txt");
$num = count($a_temp); //количество строк в файле temp66.txt
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
$string = $a_temp[$i]; 
$string = substr($string, 20, -2);
//припудрим строки
$trans = array("/" => ".", "\"" => "");
$string = strtr($string, $trans);
$arr = explode(',', $string);
unset($arr[0]);
unset($arr[1]);
unset($arr[2]);
unset($arr[8]);
$arr = implode(' ', $arr);
echo $arr;
```

Comment: Замену слэша на точку забыли.

Comment: @VenZell подправил.

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо! А вот у тебя есть идеи, почему мой вариант, работавший всё время безотказно, вдруг отвалился? Я прям расстроилась.(

Answer (score 0):

Можно через патерны попробовать

```
$string = '0000000438,add,file,10/24/2015,06:57:06,"Bank","6.20.31.32.00","2031/Main",';
$new =  implode(" ", preg_replace("[/]", ".", array_slice(preg_split("/\"?[\s,]\"?+/", $string), 3, 5)));
var_dump($new);
```

Разбиваем строку в массив через **[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)**, далее **[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)** выкидывает ненужные эелементы массива, **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** заменяет "**/**" на "**.**", и наконец **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** собирает строку обратно